# Multiline link formatting

Tags: feature-request, chat, hyperlinks

The `[title](url)` is no longer formatted when the chat post is multi-lined

Examples: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22017116#22017116, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22017040#22017040

Comment: ...the same goes for magic URLs.